# How to Use Nested Curly Braces in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Hi everyone I am trying to use curly braces like this

```
 <a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/edit">Edit</a> 
Output:
     http://localhost/projects/2/edit

but actual output should come like this 
    http://localhost/scrumwala/public/projects/2/edit
```

How i Can get my project url like this please suggest.

Comment: Try using some of [these](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls) functions

- {!! route('projects', $project->id); !!}
- {!! action('ProjectController@show', $project->id);  !!}

Here are two possible solution

Comment: Why is your URL going through the **public** folder? Do you use a virtual host or **artisan serve**?

Comment: Thank you For your replies I got the solution    {{URL::to('/projects')}}/{{$project->id}}

Comment: if `$project` is a model, then you are providing a url that contains the id of your database rows to anyone who can access your site. This is bad practice, since hackers can take advantage of this information.

Comment: @henrik Thanx for pointing out.I will keep in my mind..